# Postman - using same request with different variables within request url

Tags: javascript, postman

Is it possible to use the same request with variables within the request URL that get set each time the request is sent?

For example:

I have two different Id variables: DocumentTypeId1, DocumentTypeId2

My request URL is {{CrmGateway}}/Documents/{{DocumentTypeId1}}/Approved

Once this has been sent the first time I would like the {{DocumentTypeId1}} to change to
{{DocumentTypeId2}} and then resend the request and then move onto a different request.

[image: Screenshot of request url]

[image: Sceenshot of request url 2]

Comment: Doing exactly what you want is not possible, but you could actually modify the value of the variable with a script in "tests" tab. If you're running test sets you an also provide a list of values i you want to execute that request with 15 different values for example.

Comment: It feels like you're currently doing this already by using environment variables for those values. Why can't this be done with 2 separate requests? If you use the collection runner, you can add those id values to a CSV or JSON file, then use a single request with a single variable reference in the URL.

Comment: You could perhaps have the server return a `303: See Other` header, with your `DocumentTypeId2` as url, and have PostMan follow redirects automatically. But I am unsure whether this will fill your specific use-case.